Computing cohomology ring $H^{\ast}(\mathbb{R} P^{\infty};\mathbb{Z}_{2k})$
As the title suggests we want to compute the cohomology ring $H^{\ast}(\mathbb{R} P^{\infty};\mathbb{Z}_{2k})$. For the rest of my question I will denote $\mathbb{R} P^{\infty}= X$.
To do this we have a ring map $\tilde{f}: \mathbb{Z}_{2k}\to \mathbb{Z}_2$. Now extending this we can have a cochain from $f^{\ast}: C^{\ast}(X;\mathbb{Z}_{2k})\to C^{\ast}(X;\mathbb Z_2)$. Analyzing this map we can see for the case $k$ odd we have isomorphism in cohomology for every index.

The hard part is to compute the cohomology ring when $k$ is even, we have the following co chain map We note that $f^{\ast}: H^{i}(X;\mathbb{Z}_{2k}) \to H^{i}(X; \mathbb{Z}_{2})$ is isomorphism for $i$ even and this map is zero for odd $i$. If $\alpha$ generates $H^1(X;\mathbb{Z}_{2k})$ and $\beta$ generates $H^2(X;\mathbb{Z}_{2})$ we can see $2 \alpha = 2\beta =0$ and $\alpha^2 =0$ (using $f^{\ast}$ and naturality of cup product). Also, note that $\beta^i$ generates $H^{2i}(X;\mathbb{Z}_{2k})$.
I have seen from various sources that the cohomology ring should be $\mathbb{Z}_{2k}[\alpha,\beta]/(2\alpha, 2 \beta, \alpha^2)$. For this I want to show $\alpha \beta^l\neq 0$. I have seen a proof using bockstin homomorphism which is very nice also I have another proof using a similar computation given in Hatcher.

But I got a suggestion of doing this in a slightly different way. I have no idea how to proceed in that way. It is as follows:
We can treat $\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ as an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}_{2k}$ and so we have a map $g^{\ast}: H^{\ast}(X;\mathbb{Z}_{2}) \to H^{\ast}(X;\mathbb{Z}_{2k})$. This is a $H^{\ast}(X;\mathbb{Z}_{2k})$-module morphism (why?) using this module map together with the ring morphism $f^{\ast}: H^{\ast}(X;\mathbb{Z}_{2k})\to H^{\ast}(X;\mathbb{Z}_{2})$ we can conclude $\alpha \beta^l \neq 0$.
I am having difficulties understanding what it is supposed to mean and how we are giving $H^{\ast}(X;\mathbb{Z}_{2})$ a $H^{\ast}(X;\mathbb{Z}_{2k})$-module structure. (I am sure the $H^{\ast}(X;\mathbb{Z}_{2k})$-module structure can not come from $f^{\ast}$ as then $g^{\ast}\circ f^{\ast}$ would be zero). Any help or suggestion regarding this is appreciated.

As you can see I have done a minor edit in your question. If you denote the co-chain map as $f$ and the corresponding map in cohomology as $f^{\ast}$, it might create a confusion. At the end you wrote $g^{\ast}\circ f^{\ast}$ is zero, there it seems you have taken $g^{\ast} \circ f^{\ast} = (f\circ g)^{\ast}$. But in reality both $f$ and $g$ are co-chain map so you can't do it. That's why without loss of generality we may assume $f^{\ast},g^{\ast}$ represents the maps in c-chain level and a map in cohomology. I will clearly mention in which context I am using the notation.

At first we have a ring map $f^{\ast}: H^{\ast}(X;\mathbb{Z}_{2k})\to H^{\ast}(X;\mathbb{Z}_{2})$ which helps us to give $H^{\ast}(X;\mathbb{Z}_{2})$ a $H^{\ast}(X;\mathbb{Z}_{2k})$-graded module structure by $r. m = f^{\ast}(r)\smile m$. As it's provided in the hint $g^{\ast}: H^{\ast}(X;\mathbb{Z}_{2}) \to H^{\ast}(X;\mathbb{Z}_{2k})$ is a $H^{\ast}(X;\mathbb{Z}_{2k})$-module morphism that preserves the grading.
To see that, begin with $g^{\ast}$. Note that it's an isomorphism for odd indexed cohomology and it's trivial map for even indices. Let, $r \in H^{\ast}(X;\mathbb{Z}_{2k})$ and $m \in H^{\ast}(X;\mathbb{Z}_{2})$ and $\deg r$ is even, then $g^{\ast}(r.m)= 0 = rg^{\ast}(m)$ when $\deg m$ is even. And when $\deg m$ is odd we have $g^{\ast}(r.m)=r g^{\ast}(m)$. Similarly other cases can be checked.
Therefore we will have the following commutative diagram:  we get this diagram by using basic module structure and here we are not using any naturality of cup product under maps. The above diagram can be simplified in a very specific way (which is required for our case). 
If we call $\gamma$ to be the generator of $H^{1}(X;\mathbb{Z}_{2})$ then $\gamma \otimes \beta ^{\ell}$ maps to $\alpha \otimes \beta^{\ell}$ under $g^{\ast} \otimes 1$.
Also, it goes to $\gamma \smile f^{\ast}(\beta^{\ell})$ under the composition of the maps in first row. Both $\gamma$ and $f^{\ast}(\beta)$ are generator of the respective cohomologies (as you have noted) so it's a generator of $H^{2\ell+1}(X;\mathbb{Z}_{2})$ and since $g^{\ast}$ is iso. in odd index so the image of it under $g^{\ast}$ is non-zero. Thus by the commutativity of the above diagram $\alpha \smile \beta ^{\ell}\neq 0$.

I don't under stand how is $g^{\ast}$ a module morphism.

See my second para.

How you get $g^{\ast}(r.m) = r g^{\ast} (m)$

Chcek $g^{\ast},f^{\ast}$ at the cochain level

I am not sure about it, I'll surely check that.
